# Get RGB channels of an image

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I am trying to split a three-dimensional numpy array into its red, green and blue layers.

So far I have this function:
    s_W is the screen width and s_H the screen height

```
def webcam_func(cap, s_W, s_H):
    # Capture frame by frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    if ret:
        # make a np array from the frame
        frame_one = np.array(frame)

        # seperate the height, width and depth of the array
        arr_height = (frame_one.shape[0])
        arr_width = (frame_one.shape[1])
        arr_rgb = (frame_one.shape[2])

        # This is what I tried to get a copy of the whole 
        # array except for the first depth slice, 
        # which I believe is RED channel
        green_frame = frame_one[0:arr_height, 0:arr_width, 0:1]

        # flip the frame
        frame_flip = np.rot90(green_frame)

        # create a pygame surface and then scale the surface
        webcam_frame = pyg.surfarray.make_surface(frame_flip)
        webcam_frame = pyg.transform.scale(webcam_frame, (s_W, s_H))

        return(webcam_frame)
```

However, I'm getting this error when trying to create a surface from the sliced frame.

`ValueError: must be a valid 2d or 3d array`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the rgb channels of an image which is represented by a numpy array, you can use:

```
b,g,r = cv2.split(frame)
```

or:

```
b = frame[:,:,0]
g = frame[:,:,1]
r = frame[:,:,2]
```

So you can change your function:

```
def webcam_func(cap, s_W, s_H):
    # Capture frame by frame
    ret, frame_one = cap.read()

    if ret:


    # seperate the height, width and depth of the array
        arr_height = (frame_one.shape[0])
        arr_width = (frame_one.shape[1])
        arr_rgb = (frame_one.shape[2])

        green_frame = frame_one[:,:, 1] #This will return the green channel

    # flip the frame
        frame_flip = np.rot90(green_frame)

    # create a pygame surface and then scale the surface
        webcam_frame = pyg.surfarray.make_surface(frame_flip)
        webcam_frame = pyg.transform.scale(webcam_frame, (s_W, s_H))

        return(webcam_frame)
```

Comment: Okay so I've tried both ways and they work, except I'm getting over saturated mixtures of the colours. https://www.pinterest.co.uk/pin/450219293997433425#
Any ideas why this would be the case? I've used the cv2.split method of separating the colours.

Comment: Hi @HenryJames. Sorry I don't know why that would happen. Not experienced with pygame surface. Maybe ask a new question about it? Also, I hope my solution for retrieving the channels worked for you.

Comment: Yes! Okay no worries. And yes all your answers helped and are correct. I suspect the issue is somewhere else.

Comment: For some reason my outputs were always getting reversed for red and blue. Now I got to know why. The 0th slab is for blue while the 2nd slab is for red channel.